# Try catch method for capturing query related exception laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am new to this try catch exception method so it will be helpful if you could provide detailed explanation of the answer to implement on the other files.

I am working on Laravel 5 and i want to use try catch while a put or post request is sent to the database. Below is my coding structure.

```
try{
        $result = DB::table('myTable')
                    ->where('uniqueTitle','=',$uniqueId)
                    ->increment($field, 1);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
```

My postman output is

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 669:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
```

I have intentionally changed the column name to throw an error.

Additionally,  how do i check on the required fields too with try and catch method.

Comment: So you mean the exception is not caught? Where is that piece of code located?

Comment: Its a put request to increase the count by 1

Comment: Ok, but is it in a controller method, a route closure, another class? Also, please specify the namespace of the file where the code is located.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Laravel built in exceptions.

```
 try {
    $result = DB::table('myTable')
                ->where('uniqueTitle','=',$uniqueId)
                ->increment($field, 1);
 } catch (QueryException $e) {
   echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
   echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
 }
```

Remember to insert `use` to declare Exception's classes.

In this case:

```
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use PDOException;
```